# Program for dropdownlist, when code has no id or xpath

Tags: testng

I need to write program for a dropdownlist using webdriver in testNG.

See my below HTML code; it contains only a class. Without id and XPath, how am I supposed to write the dropdownlist program?

```
<select class="dojoxGridSelect">
<option value="Name">Name</option>
<option value="Display Name">Display Name</option>
<option value="Region Name">Region Name</option>
<option value="Location">Location</option>
</select>
```

Comment: looks good. as long as it isn't supposed to do anything. What do you want to do? submit it in a form? access it via javascript? have it do something when you make a selection?

Comment: no..i have to write in testng using junit.

Comment: @vidhyashree it seems, you knowledge of testng, junit and selenium is shallow. There is no such type to things which you can write in testng using Junit.

Comment: @Priyanshu yeah i dont know selenium deeply but i know little. i need to know how i can write dropdown list using class in testng using java.is there any other way without using id, xpath.please tell me

Comment: @vidhyashree Learn it from here: http://software-testing-tutorials-automation.blogspot.in/2013/07/what-is-selenium-webdriver.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to select in Java Selenium Webdriver?**

```
WebElement dropDown = driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//select[@class='dojoxGridSelect']"));

Select mySelect = new Select(dropDown);

mySelect.selectByVisibleText("Display Name"); //or another text from your options of select
```